# cardinality of Y=$\{(x_n)\ : x_n=1\}$ for at most finitely many $n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be the set of all binary sequences i.e. $X=\{(x_n) : x_n \in \{0,1\}, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and Y be its subset such that  Y=$\{(x_n)\in X : x_n=1 \text{ for at most finitely many } n \}$. It is clear that $X$ is uncountable using Cantor's diagonalization argument.

But Y must be countable right? As I think we can enumerate it and thus have a 1-1 function with $\mathbb{N}$. Am I right?

Comment: You are right. Can you try to expand your argument? There's a couple of ways to do it. It is easier to use [Cantor-Bernstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) than to provide an explicit bijection.

Comment: Define $f:Y\to \mathbb{N}$ by $f((x_n))=\sum_n 2^{x_n}.$ It is injective, isn't it?

Comment: Hint: can you think of a way of converting an element of $Y$ into a natural number in a nice way?

Comment: All you need is a 1-to-1 (injective) function from $Y$ to $\mathbb{N}$, or to $\mathbb{Q}$.  For the latter possibility, I wonder if the function that maps $(x_{n}) \in Y$ to the rational number $\sum_{n \geq 0} x_{n} 2^{-n}$ wouldn't work.

Comment: Your guess isn't quite right because $f(1,0,0,0,\ldots)=f(0,1,0,0,\ldots)=2$. You're very close though. Try being a bit more careful.

Comment: Yes Dan. seems it is not injective. What is a good function for this case then?

Comment: You want the summands to depend on $n$, rather than the value of the sequence at that position $x_n$, so you want $1$s that are far along the sequence to contribute more. So maybe something like $\sum x_n 2^n$? I'll leave you to prove that it is injective.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that the countable union of countable sets is again countable.  If we define $U_k = \{(x_n) | x_n = 0\; \forall k > N\}$, then we can observe the following:

1) Each $U_k$ is a subset of $Y$ since each $(x_n)\in U_k$ contains at most $k$ entries which are equal to 1.  This means that $\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}} U_k \subseteq Y$.

2) Each $U_k$ is finite.  In fact, $|U_k| = 2^k$.

3) $Y \subseteq \bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}} U_k$.

1 and 3 together show that $Y = \bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}} U_k$.  Altogether we have shown that $Y$ is the countable union of countable sets, and hence $Y$ itself is countable.

Comment: Sir how can justify 3)? Let consider the sequence $(a_n)$ with all of its terms $0$ except it's first term and 1000th term are $1$ then $(a_n)$ is in $Y$ But is it in $U_k$ for some $k$?